# Filter complex metric in grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana

Is it possible to filter values from comlex metric in grafana?
For example:

`SELECT sum(one) + sum(two) FROM "table" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval)`

I need to show only positive sum `sum(one) + sum(two) > 0`

In sql I would use alias and `HAVING` clause like:

`SELECT sum(one) + sum(two) AS S FROM "table" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval) HAVING S > 0`

However that does not work in grafana. 
How can I achieve this result without creating a new sum column in back-end database?

[image: version]

[EDIT]: My grafana GUI looks like this:

[image]
After clicking on "pen" button:

[image]

Comment: Please specify the version of Grafana you're using.

Answer (score 2):

As of August 2016, the [`HAVING` clause](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5266) is not yet available in InfluxDB so finding all points where `sum(one) + sum(two) > 0` is not possible directly in InfluxDB without using a continuous query to create an intermediate series.

However, Grafana does allow a minimum y-axis value to be set, which means any negative values will not be shown.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This answers just a part of your question but I was able to do the following in grafana+influxdb datasource:

[image]

Which selects the sum of one value if >0.

The problem is that it is not possible to select two different values in one query. But maybe you can workaround this problem with two querys in one graph.

Comment: That doesn't look like what I am seeing in grafana =\
Added some screenshots of my GUI.
Also I think that I was unclear about my question: I have to filter a SUM of two timeseries. 

So the result should be like `sum(one) + sum(two) > 0`, not just `sum(one) > 0`

Comment: yea the addition you are trying to do of two sum is not possible. You should also think about updating to a new version

Comment: Wait, I am able to show `sum(one) + sum(two)`, but can't find a way to show only positive parts of that curve

Comment: @MaxPY you mean something like this?: SELECT "value" FROM "one","two" WHERE "value" > 0

Comment: Update: does this work ? SELECT sum("value") FROM "one","two" WHERE "value" > 0